# how to mock node-redis using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, node-redis

i am using [jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest) and trying to mock [node-redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis) using [redis-mock](https://github.com/yeahoffline/redis-mock).

```js
// redis.js

const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 });

// redis.test.js

const redisMock = require("redis-mock");

describe("redis", () => {
  jest.doMock("redis", () => jest.fn(() => redisMock));
  const redis = require("./redis");
});
```

when i run the tests, i get an error

> TypeError: redis.createClient is not a function

feels to me that i am doing something wrong when using `jest.doMock()`.

would appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
import redis from 'redis-mock'
jest.mock('redis', () => redis)
```

I do not include the `redis` library in the test at all, but I include it only in the file which contains the tested class. (The file with tested class is, of course, included in the test file.)

Comment: could you please give me an example code?

Comment: @UWU_SANDUN did you get the example code?

Answer (score 12):

If you are using [jest](https://jestjs.io), the switching of the mock and the actual implementation is [possible automatically](https://github.com/yeahoffline/redis-mock#jest). Works great for CI.

`jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    // other properties...
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.redis-mock.js'],
};
```

`jest.setup.redis-mock.js`

```
jest.mock('redis', () => jest.requireActual('redis-mock'));
```

Comment: is this working. please give me an example code?

Comment: Just as a note, this works up to `node-redis` version 3. From 4 they changed the way the client is configured and methods work and currently there doesn't seem to be a working mocking library